# Why can't I use this approach in C++ with 'char' instead of a 'string' approach?

Tags: c++, string, char

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char name;
    char city;

    cout << "Please enter your name" << endl
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Please enter your city name" << endl
    cin >> city;

    cout << "Your name is  " << name << "and live in" << city << endl

    return 0;
}
```

I can't see if I'm missing something, but I get an error in the line 'cin >> name;'. How can I fix it?

Comment: A `char` is one character.

Comment: You forgot to put semicolons at the end of the `cout << ...` lines.

Comment: I see, hence the reason why a string is essential to actually do this question, thank you.

Comment: In C++, the way to handle stuff like this is using `std::string`s. You could use C-style char *arrays*, but please don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 problems:
A `char` can only hold one character, so you need to use an [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and you have missing semicolons at the end of the lines.

```
// Here
cout << "Please enter your name" << endl
// Here
cout << "Please enter your city name" << endl
// And here
cout << "Your name is  " << name << "and live in" << city << endl
```

---

A semi-colon is required for the compiler to know that you're terminating the current statement. This is mainly for removing ambiguities and it allows us to do things like this:

```
x = some_routine(boost::some_very_long_function_name0<type>(some_args0),
                 boost::some_very_long_function_name1<type>(some_args1),
                 boost::some_very_long_function_name2<type>(some_args2));
//                                     Terminates the current statement ^
```

This way, we don't have to deal with very, very long lines. It's a Win-Win.

---

One last thing: `cin >> name` terminates when it reaches a space, so a name like `"Mohammad Ali"` would be read as `"Mohammad"`. For this particular purpose in which more than one word is acceptable, you should use `std::getline(cin, str)` where `str` is an `std::string`. This will terminate the string when it reaches a `'\n'`.

(You can also give [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) a third argument to choose your own delimiter: `std::getline(cin, str, '\t')`. That makes it terminate when it hits a `'\t'` character. `std::getline` has the third `char` parameter/argument as `'\n'` by default.)

Comment: You might want to mention ``getline(cin, str)``, in case his names have more than one word in them.

Comment: Thank you alot! Also, thanks to all for your contribution :) @amaurea thank you as well that is also a great idea which I just used as well!

Answer (score 1):

A character variable can contain just a single character. Like `char a='x';`.

If you want to store a string in C++ use,

```
const char * a = "name";
```

or

```
string a="name";
```

Comment: Also, it would be `const char *`, since it's a string literal.